# Compared two arrays for difference

Tags: php, arrays, json

## From MySQL query:

$array1

```
array ( 0 => array ( 'skill' => 56, ), 1 => array ( 'skill' => 10, ), 2 => array ( 'skill' => 76, ), 3 => array ( 'skill' => 77, ), 4 => array ( 'skill' => 57, ), )
```

$array2

```
array ( 0 => array ( 'skill' => '56', ), 1 => array ( 'skill' => '10', ), 2 => array ( 'skill' => '76', ), 3 => array ( 'skill' => '77', ), 4 => array ( 'skill' => '13', ), )
```

My solution(does not work):

```
$total_in_array= count($array1);
$diff = strcmp(json_encode($array1), json_encode($array2)); //get the matching skills

//if zero then just display zero
if($diff < 1){
    $applicant_matching_rate = "0";
}else{ // do some math to get the % value
    $applicant_matching_sum = (($diff/$total_in_array)*100);
    $applicant_matching_rate = ($applicant_matching_sum-100)*(-1);
}

echo $applicant_matching_rate;
```

**What I want:**
*I want to compare these two arrays for differences then display it as a percentage amount, So $Array1 has 5 values and $array2 has 4 matching values
that should then display 80%.*

I am new to Stackoverflow if I did something incorrectly please comment and tell me so that I can fix it>

Have a good day & thx for reading...

Comment: please `var_export()` your arrays to facilitate reproduction, thx

Comment: okay i will do that.

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Errors? Unexpected results?

Comment: on my localhost it gives me 80% but when i uploaded it to my server it gives me -280% @El_Vanja

Comment: You'll need to specify valid arrays, like `$array1 = [['skill' => 56], ['skill' => 10], ['skill' => 76], ['skill' => 77], ['skill' => 57]];`, then you could use `array_column($array1, 'skill');` to extract the values for easy use.

Comment: i checked my database and everything is exactly the same

Comment: okay i will try that

Comment: something like [this](https://3v4l.org/TPifU)

Comment: @Code4R7 What makes you think the arrays are invalid?

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH GUYS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! El_Vanja and berend i have been struggling with this.

Comment: The array are not invalid not as far as my knowledge goes @Code4R7

Comment: At some point in history, the arrays were written down in this form: `Array ( 0 => Array ( [skill] => 56, ), ...` with arrays as indexes.

Comment: @berend please help me for some reason it produced 50% even tho there is 4 matching?

Comment: @berend it was me, sorry I am stupid.  I forgot to use array_pop() for the last empty one in the array.

Comment: @berend :> have a good night and hope you stay safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer to my problem:

```
<?php

$array1 = array ( 0 => array ( 'skill' => 56, ), 1 => array ( 'skill' => 10, ), 2 => array ( 'skill' => 76, ), 3 => array ( 'skill' => 77, ), 4 => array ( 'skill' => 57, ), );
$array2 = array ( 0 => array ( 'skill' => '56', ), 1 => array ( 'skill' => '10', ), 2 => array ( 'skill' => '76', ), 3 => array ( 'skill' => '77', ), 4 => array ( 'skill' => '13', ), );

$count = count($array1);
$hits = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    if($array1[$i]['skill'] == $array2[$i]['skill']) $hits++;
}
echo 'match: ' . ($hits / $count)*100 . '%';
```

This was proposed by @berend
And I want to thank @El_Vanja for the help.